# Why adding a tab is not displaying in my Lightning app

Tags: lightning, lightning-experience

I am very new to lightning experience. So this question can be very silly.

I have added my custom object tabs into my custom app (managed app installed). The screenshot looks like this:

[image]

However, when I turn to my Vision6 app, it still looks like the tabs are not there. I mean Vision6 Folders and Vision6 Lists tabs.

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do your profiles have the permission for the Tab? Adding application does not guarantee you see them unless your profile or permission set allows it

Comment: @MohithShrivastava should be. I can see them in Salesforce classic. And I am System Admin

Comment: Are they object tabs or visualforce tabs ?

Comment: @MohithShrivastava they are all object tabs

Comment: @MohithShrivastava And I don't see a place for tab access though... I definitely have access to those custom objects

Comment: Have you tried adding them in navigation menus ? Navigation menus is visible in set up only in the lightning experience

Comment: A tab access is available in the profile in the same place where you see object access

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Yes, I have tried. But navigation menu is per profile, not per app. But I guess I found out the solution now. I will put an answer.

Answer (score 4):

I have just figured out. It is something very simple - I should tick the Overwrite Users' Personal Custom App Customizations checkbox. The tick box is shown in the below screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This probably belongs as a comment but I can't do that as I don't have a reputation of 50 yet. Anyhow, has this "Overwrite User's Personal Custom App Customizations" been replicated in the Lightning Experience version of the tab navigation configuration? I don't find it, and in fact can't find any way to make a new tab automatically appear in the navigation for all existing users (they each have to add it manually!).

Thanks in advance for any insights on this.